# $(2L+1)(2S+1)$-fold degeneracy of the energy eigenvalues of many-electron atoms in absence of spin-orbit interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

In the case of many-electron atoms, the Hamiltonian (neglecting the spin-orbit interaction) is given by $$H=H_c+H_1$$
where $H_c$ is the Hamiltonian in the central field approximation and $H_1$ is the noncentral part of the electrostatic interaction. The Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with $L^2, L_z, S^2, S_z$. Thus, in this case, the energy eigenstates are labelled as $$|LSM_LM_S\rangle.$$

Each energy level is $(2L+1)(2S+1)$-fold degenerate if and only if the eigenvalues of $H=H_c+H_1$ are independent of $M_L$ and $M_S$. But we cannot solve the eigenvalues of $H=H_c+H_1$ exactly. How does one argue that the energy eigenvalues are independent of  $M_L$ and $M_S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators $L_x$, $L_y$, $S_x$, $S_y$ also commute with the Hamiltonian $H$. Therefore, the unitary operators of spatial and spin rotation
$$
U_{\theta_1,\phi_1,\psi_1} = \exp\left(i\psi_1\left(\cos(\theta_1)L_z + \sin(\theta_1)(\cos(\phi_1)L_x + \sin(\phi_1)L_y)\right)\right),
$$
$$
Q_{\theta_2,\phi_2,\psi_2} = \exp\left(i\psi_2\left(\cos(\theta_2)S_z + \sin(\theta_2)(\cos(\phi_2)S_x + \sin(\phi_2)S_y)\right)\right),
$$
commute with the Hamiltonian. For this reason, vectors of the form
$$
Q_{\theta_2,\phi_2,\psi_2}U_{\theta_1,\phi_1,\psi_1}|LSLS\rangle\tag{1}
$$
are eigenvectors of $H$ with eigenvalue equal to $E_{LSLS}$, which is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $|LSLS\rangle$. From the theory of angular and spin momentum it is known that vectors (1) are linear combinations of eigenvectors with all possible values of $M_L$ and $M_S$:
$$
Q_{\theta_2,\phi_2,\psi_2}U_{\theta_1,\phi_1,\psi_1}|LSLS\rangle = \sum_{M_L=-L}^L \sum_{M_S=-S}^S\Psi(M_L,M_S)|LSM_LM_S\rangle.
\tag{2}
$$
Depending on the angles $\theta_i,\phi_i,\psi_i$, all coefficients $\Psi(M_L,M_S)$ in (2) can simultaneously have non-zero values. The Hamiltonian $H$ can have such an eigenvector (2) only if all eigenvectors $|LSM_LM_S\rangle$ correspond to the same energy $E_{LSLS}$.